# R: Find certain value for each row from a subset of columns

Tags: r

I'm new to R and this forum so apologies for a rather fundamental question.

I have a bunch of columns (i.e. variables, because it's a data frame) where the colnames all start out with the same name but end on a distinct number, say: variable_0, variable_1, and so on up to 12.

For each of those columns each row contains numbers, again from zero to twelve.

I'm interested in finding (for each row) the value at which the trailing number of the colname matches the value of that particular variable:

```
v_0 v_1 v_2 v_3
1   2   2   2
1   2   3   3
```

In this example, what I would want to have is a new variable x that equals 2 for row 1 (because v_i=i only for i=2) and 3 for row2.

Ideally, the code would also include a solution for the case where there exist more than one matches per row: create a variable y that is one if # of matches exceed one and zero otherwise; set x to the first match.

Help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
trail = as.numeric(gsub(".*_([0-9]*)","\\1",names(df)))
df$x = apply(df, 1, function(u) if(all(trail!=u)) NA else trail[match(T,trail==u)])

#> df
#  v_0 v_1 v_2 v_3 x
#1   1   2   2   2 2
#2   1   2   3   3 3
```

This way if you have - in case - crappy data like:

```
df = data.frame(v_0=c(1,1,2), v_1=c(1,2,5), v_2=2:4, v_3=2:4)
#  v_0 v_1 v_2 v_3
#1   1   1   2   2
#2   1   2   3   3
#3   2   5   4   4

df$x = apply(df, 1, function(u) if(all(trail!=u)) NA else trail[match(T,trail==u)])
#  v_0 v_1 v_2 v_3  x
#1   1   1   2   2  1
#2   1   2   3   3  3
#3   2   5   4   4 NA
```

`trail` contains the trailing number of each column (I supposed the key delimiter is `_`). Then for each row we check which number equal its trail number in the column (we use `apply` to loop, second argument `1` indicates we loop over the rows - `2` is for the columns). If there is no match, we return `NA`. If there is one or more, we take the first number.

Comment: Nice, but you should really explain what each part of the code is doing

Comment: Done through examples ;)

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you. Just for those interested, I modified the code a bit because I'm actually only interested in this being done for some subset of variables:

`myvarlist <- paste("var_", 0:12, sep="")`
`trail <- as.numeric(gsub(".*_([0-9]*)","\\1",names(df[myvarlist])))`
`df$x <- apply(df, 1, function(u) if(all(trail!=u)) NA else trail[match(T,trail==u)])`

Comment: Can't edit my comment anymore but note that there is a mistake in the last bit, should start with `df$x <- apply(df[myvarlist],`...

Answer (score 0):

Another option using @ColonelBeauvel's data is

```
trail <- as.numeric(sub('[^0-9]+', '', names(df)))
indx <- df==trail[col(df)]
df$x <- trail[max.col(indx, 'first')* NA^!rowSums(indx)]
df
#  v_0 v_1 v_2 v_3  x
#1   1   1   2   2  1
#2   1   2   3   3  3
#3   2   5   4   4 NA
```